# Custom Home button in Orbeon Form Builder Summary page

Tags: orbeon

I have a task to change the behavior of 'Home' button in Form Builder Summary page.
[image]
When user click home button, it will navigate to the website that I want (example here: https://google.com)

Ref: https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-builder#action-buttons-on-the-form-builder-summary-page

I tried this code below but it didn't work. It still back to Form Runner Summary page.

```
*properties-local.xml

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.summary.process.home.orbeon.builder">
        navigate(uri = "https://google.com")
</property>
```

Comment: @avernet Could you help me on this ?

Comment: @avernet I got the same question with the button "delete". Could you have some suggestions?

Comment: @ebruchez Do you know anyway to custom this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently that URL is not configurable. The only thing you can do is [omit the Home button](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/form-runner-summary-page#buttons-on-the-summary-page).

It would be nice to able to do that and I added [RFE #5214](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5214).